# I can't put the names of the queries in the correct place. Error msg can be variable not found or erived table must have its own alias

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join

Could someone please help me to find this error? It seems I have named some queries in a wrong place. I copy and paste:
Error

SQL query: Documentation

```
SELECT `Schools`.`School Name` , `Studentlogin`.`School Code` ,   `Studentlogin`.`Group` , `NewResults`.`Test` , `NewResults`.`Question` , `NewResults`.`Blank` , `NewResults`.`A` , `NewResults`.`B` , `NewResults`.`C` , `NewResults`.`D` , `NewResults`.`E` , `NewResults`.`Correct` , `Schools`.`State` , `Schools`.`District` , `Run_Date` , `Studentlogin`.`AutoId` AS Ind1
FROM Schools
INNER JOIN Studentlogin ON `Studentlogin`.`School Code` = `Schools`.`School Code`
INNER JOIN NewResults AS T1 ON ( NewResults.Student = Studentlogin.AutoId )
INNER JOIN (

SELECT Max( `Run_Date` ) AS Maximus, Studentlogin.AutoId AS Ind2
FROM Schools
INNER JOIN Studentlogin AS T2 ON ( `Studentlogin`.`School Code` =`Schools`.`School Code` )
INNER JOIN NewResults ON ( NewResults.Student = Studentlogin.AutoId )
WHERE (
NewResults.Test = '27'
)
AND (
`Schools`.`School Code` = '9'
)
) ON ( T1.Ind1 = T2.Ind2
AND Run_Date = Maximus )
GROUP BY Studentlogin.AutoId, Question
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Add alias in the subquery.

Comment: The subquery has it, may be in the wrong place : FROM Schools
INNER JOIN Studentlogin AS T2

Comment: Neither in this place: SELECT Max( `Run_Date` ) as Maximus,Studentlogin.AutoId as Ind2
FROM Schools AS T2 ......  same error message.

Comment: If I put in this way: SELECT Max( `Run_Date` ) as Maximus,Studentlogin.AutoId as Ind2
FROM Schools  Inner Join Studentlogin   on (`Studentlogin`.`School Code` = `Schools`.`School Code`) Inner Join NewResults  on (NewResults.Student = Studentlogin.AutoId)
where ( NewResults.Test = '27')  AND (`Schools`.`School Code` = '9') 
) AS T2 on (T1.Ind1=T2.Ind2 and Run_Date=Maximus)
GROUP BY Studentlogin.AutoId,Question  I receive another error message:   MySQL said: Documentation
#1054 - Unknown column 'NewResults.Test' in 'field list'